# In MYSQL, is it possible to get records from two tables where both the tables have comma separated values?

Tags: mysql

I am having problem to find records from two tables where both the tables have common name field and both fields have comma separated values.

For instance,

`table-1` have `"a,b,c"` value

```
id | name
----------
1  | a,b,c
```

and `table-2` have `"a,c,d,e,f"` value

```
id | name
---------------
1  | a,c,d,e,f
```

Now I want to compare both tables where at least one character matches in both.
So is it possible to get records where at least one character matches into both fields or not?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well,this is one way to learn about normalization.

Comment: @Mihai ...Or NoSQL

Comment: Short answer. No. Because the premise of the question is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the UNION statement to combine rows in both tables; include only the columns that need to compare. The returned result set is used for the comparison. Considering table-1 as t1 and table-2 as t2.

```
SELECT t1.pk, t1.c1
FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.pk, t2.c1
FROM t2
```

Second, group the records based on the primary key and columns that need to compare. If the values in the columns that need to compare are identical, the COUNT(*) returns 2, otherwise the  COUNT(*) returns 1.

See the following query:

```
SELECT pk, c1
FROM
 (
   SELECT t1.pk, t1.c1
   FROM t1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t2.pk, t2.c1
   FROM t2
)  t
GROUP BY pk, c1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY pk
```

MySQL compare two tables example

```
SELECT id,title
FROM (
SELECT id, title FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT id,title FROM t2
) tbl
GROUP BY id, title
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

It will return unmatched records.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks for trying to resolve my issue But for your kind information this SQL will not return what I required here.

I tried this on real data & found 2 different rows from both tables.
Please see this screenshot for reference: http://screencast.com/t/8X0vj1Yxk6

As per my requirement I need to compare both tables only for one field which is comma separated & if after comparison of both fields any one value matches then it should return true or false. Order of values may not same in fields.

I hope someone will have solution to get what I am expecting.